# Difference between Apple part numbers 661-5480 and 661-6362 for MacBook Pro 15" Mid-2010 2.66GHz logic board

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, repair, gpu, logicboard

I've been asked to replace the logic board of a mid-2010 MacBook Pro 15" Unibody 2.66GHz Core i7 laptop.

When I check the exploded view of my Apple Technician Guide for this MacBook Pro, it lists part number 661-5480 for the 2.66GHz model. However, upon checking various stockists I see both 661-5480 and 661-6362 used interchangeably for this particular logic board.

My copy of the Apple Technician Guide for this computer is dated 5 August 2010. Now, since Apple had to implement a [recall program](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203554) for this particular model due to issues with the GPU (NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M) and/or the on-board Intel HD Graphics, it's clear this occurred **after** my copy of the Apple Technician Guide was produced.

**MY QUESTION:**

- **I am wondering whether the two part numbers signify that one was the original logic board part number and the other was for the replacement logic board?**

Regardless of your answer above, please advise how you know.

My concern is that I would want to avoid any used or refurbished logic boards with the original part number.